# Calculate max normalized mean subarray in O(n)

Tags: r, arrays, algorithm, performance

This is a variation of max sum subarray problem but there's a little twist (also similar to max average subarray with size k). Instead of finding the maximum sum, I'd like to find the normalized mean, which is `sum/sqrt(length)`.

for example, if this is my array, `c(1, -3, -4, 2, 6, 8, -4, -3, -5, 1, 7, -9, 3, 2)`, the maximum sum subarray problem will output the max_sum = 16, and the subarray would be `c(2, 6, 8)`, which you can achieve this in linear time with Kadane's algorithm. In my case, the output would be `9.899495`, and the subarray is `c(6, 8)`.

This obviously could easily be done in `O(n^2)`, but I'm trying to see if it could be done in `O(n)`. I tried to come up with a variation of the Kadane's algorithm but it wasn't all accurate (compared with `O(n^2)` algorithm). I used `r` but you're welcomed to use any language, or pseudocode and I did my simulations like so:

```
set.seed(1) #I tried from 1 to 20 for comparison
n=30000
z <- rnorm(n)
normalized_mean_subarray(z)
```

Ideally, the output should have max value, subarray start and subarray_end, but max value alone is as great! Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

I'll provide one O(n^2) method just as a reference. For n=10000, it will run for about 1.5 minutes, so it's okay for checking the results.

A couple of you asked for an example with negative values. When `n=2000` and  `set.seed(1)`, the max_interval is 4.171375, and it's from 1270 to 1295. If you check the values in that interval (`print(z[1270:1295])`), you'll be able to see many negative values.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 2000
z <- rnorm(n)

Z <- function(I) {
  (length(I)**-0.5) * sum(z[I])
}

max_interval <- 0

start_time <- Sys.time()

for (window in 1:(n-1)) {
  normalizer <- (window**-0.5)
  base <- Z(1:window)
  max_interval_window <- 0

  for (i in 2:(n-window)){
    new_interval <- base + normalizer*(z[i+window-1] - z[i-1])
    max_interval_window <- ifelse(new_interval > max_interval_window, new_interval, max_interval_window)
    base <- new_interval
  }

  max_interval <- max(max_interval, max_interval_window)
}

end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time - start_time)

max_interval
```

This is only one way of achieving O(n^2), and it's probably on the slower end, the goal is always to do this in linear time (hopefully doable).

Comment: @Onyambu Why do we need to skip negative number? I mean yes, it would be nice to have a subarray with no negative values, but I feel like if you skip them, you're likely to get a local maximum. I've had simulations where largest subarray contains multiple negative values.

Comment: I've edited the post and added an example @גלעדברקן

Comment: Because I'm not looking for a maximum sum subarray? I hope I stated that clearly in the post. @Onyambu

Comment: @Onyambu You can try `c(100,-1,100)`, where `-1` should not be omitted.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding yes OP did talk of normalize. Thats what I missed

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the max value of an element in the array?

Comment: @Dave Not sure what you meant by constraints on max value. I suppose you are trying to say whether the max value is greater than 0? Technically, no constraints, just pure max normalized value.

Comment: @timxymo1225 I mean, is there any limit to how large a single element in the input array can be?

Comment: @Dave in theory, a good algorithm should work on any cases right? I mostly use simulation data that follows standard normal, but feel free to use any data.

Comment: @timxymo1225 Not necessarily. Some approaches might work well if the range of possible inputs is limited, but not solve the general problem. Regardless, happy to consider the general problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an exact solution that empirically is fast (O(n log n)) on random Gaussian input, likely provably so if I put in some more effort. On my laptop, it usually takes less than five seconds to handle a million elements. (On the other hand, the worst case is O(n² log n), and I have a sneaking suspicion that the algorithm I’m describing is not the best way to instantiate the underlying idea.)

This is a divide and conquer algorithm. Each conquering step looks for the best solution that crosses the middle of the array. If we had a fast (max, +) convolution, we could apply to the left cumulative sums and the right cumulative sums to determine the best solution of each length, but no one knows how to do (max, +) convolution much faster than quadratic time in the worst case. We are not, however, dealing with worst-case data. Since the cumulative max vector of the cumulative sums of random Gaussian n-element vector usually has about √n distinct elements, we can throw away the other elements and do the convolution with brute force.

In R (not my weapon of choice, but maybe I’m getting better at it):

```r
# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/76143942/2144669 by ThomasIsCoding
f1 <- function(x) {
    v <- c(0, cumsum(x))
    msk <- lower.tri(matrix(NA, length(v), length(v)))
    p <- outer(v, v, `-`)[msk]
    q <- sqrt(abs(row(msk) - col(msk)))[msk]
    max(p/q)
}


f2 <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) > 50) {
        mid <- length(x)%/%2
        x_left <- x[1:mid]
        x_right <- x[(mid + 1):length(x)]
        max(f2(x_left), f2(x_right), max_crossover(x_left, x_right))
    } else {
        f1(x)
    }
}

max_crossover <- function(x_left, x_right) {
    right <- hull(x_right)
    best <- -Inf
    for (left in hull(rev(x_left))) {
        combos <- left + right
        best <- max(best, Re(combos)/sqrt(Im(combos)))
    }
    best
}

hull <- function(x) {
    cumsums <- cumsum(x)
    is_cummax <- cumsums == cummax(cumsums)
    complex(real = cumsums[is_cummax], imaginary = (1:length(x))[is_cummax])
}


f2(rnorm(1e+06))
```

Comment: I thought about using divide and conquer initially right after trying kadane's algorithm. But the idea of getting O(n) complexity kept sucking me in lol. I have to say achieving O(nlogn) is equally impressive and productive in my case. I will need to test more extreme cases, but the initial tests had good results!

Comment: What would be your preferred language to use? I can read python as well, if it makes a bit faster

Comment: @timxymo1225 Usually Python, but for this, C++.

Comment: @timxymo1225 This solution is (I hope) reasonably vectorized, so I'm skeptical that I could do a lot better in Python.

Answer (score 4):

A fast O(n^2) Rcpp solution using the observation that if `max(z) > 0`, the first and last elements of the subarray with the maximum normalized mean will both be positive. It runs in a fraction of a second for `n = 10000`.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  'List maxNormSubCpp(const NumericVector& x, const NumericVector& y, const IntegerVector& k) {
    const int n = x.length();
    IntegerVector ij = {0, 0};
    double z;
    double maxz = -1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        z = y(j) - x(i);
        z *= abs(z)/(k(j) - k(i) + 1);
        
        if (z > maxz) {
          maxz = z;
          ij(0) = i;
          ij(1) = j;
        }
      }
    }
    
    ij(0) = k(ij(0));
    ij(1) = k(ij(1));
    List out = List::create(_["Interval"] = ij, _["Maximum normalized mean"] = std::sqrt(maxz));
    return(out);
  }'
)

maxNormSub <- function(x) {
  i <- which(x > 0)
  if (length(i)) {
    cs <- c(0, cumsum(x))
    maxNormSubCpp(cs[i], cs[i + 1L], i)
  } else {
    list(rep(k <- which.max(x), 2), x[k])
  }
}
```

First, check the two arrays provided by the OP:

```
maxNormSub(c(1, -3, -4, 2, 6, 8, -4, -3, -5, 1, 7, -9, 3, 2))
#> $Interval
#> [1] 5 6
#> 
#> $`Maximum normalized mean`
#> [1] 9.899495

set.seed(1)
n <- 2000
z <- rnorm(n)
maxNormSub(z)
#> $Interval
#> [1] 1270 1295
#> 
#> $`Maximum normalized mean`
#> [1] 4.171375
```

Time two larger arrays (`n = 1e4` and `n = 1e5`).

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4L
z <- rnorm(n)
system.time(res <- maxNormSub(z))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.08    0.00    0.08
res
#> $Interval
#> [1] 8203 8207
#> 
#> $`Maximum normalized mean`
#> [1] 4.575498

set.seed(1)
n <- 1e5L
z <- rnorm(n)
system.time(res <- maxNormSub(z))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    8.33    0.00    8.32
res
#> $Interval
#> [1] 34679 34684
#> 
#> $`Maximum normalized mean`
#> [1] 4.908136
```

The time scales roughly with `n^2`.

Comment: This looks promising. I tested a few examples and got the right normalized max, will need to run more test but the first glance looks great!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking, I am a bit skeptical about solving this problem with complexity `O(n)`, since the normalized mean seems to be a non-linear measure (in contrast to the sum in the Kadane's algorithm) where the length of subarray affects the value as well.

Due to my limited knowledge, I still have to work with `O(n^2)` and try improving its efficiency from there with base R. *However, if the **feasibility of `O(n)`** is already proved or can be proved, then please forget about my solutions below and I may need more effort to make it.*

---

With base R, `f0` is an option with the classical `for` loops

```
f0 <- function(x) {
  u <- -Inf
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    for (j in i:length(x)) {
      z <- sum(x[i:j]) / sqrt(j - i + 1)
      if (z >= u) {
        u <- z
      }
    }
  }
  u
}
```

and `f1` is implemented via `cumsum` + `outer` to compute all possible normalized mean for each pair of start-to-end pair within the vector

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  v <- c(0, cumsum(x))
  msk <- lower.tri(matrix(NA, length(v), length(v)))
  p <- outer(v, v, `-`)[msk]
  q <- sqrt(abs(row(msk) - col(msk)))[msk]
  max(p / q)
}
```

## Benchmark

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000L
x <- rnorm(n)
microbenchmark(
  f0(x),
  f1(x),
  times = 10L,
  check = "equal"
)
```

which gives

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
 f0(x) 1114.4880 1164.4463 1322.2309 1195.22505 1456.8291 1727.0960    10
 f1(x)   25.8278   26.7575   33.9267   34.46985   41.4757   42.6258    10
```

Comment: I am also skeptical, more curious, if you will. Kadane's algorithm seems so simple and elegant and makes me think there should be a linear complexity solution for this problem, safe to say it's a dangerous path to follow. One of the ```O(n^2)``` algorithms I've worked on can solve ```n=30k``` in a minute and half or so. But the temptation of achieving better is itching me lol. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R implementation for Maximum Normalized Mean Subarray using Kadane's algorithm. I first wrote the C++ program for it (reminds me of my good old CP days), then converted it in R for you. This is a good interview/assessment problem for those who grinds LC/CP problems.

- Time complexity: O(N)
- Space complexity: O(1)

R program [**Playground link**](https://www.programiz.com/r/online-compiler/):

```r
calculate_max_normalized_mean_subarray <- function(arr) {
  max_so_far <- arr[1]
  max_ending_here <- arr[1]
  start_old <- 1
  start <- 1
  end <- 1
  div_b <- 1
  div_b_old <- 1

  for (i in 2:length(arr)) {
    current <- arr[i]
    div_b <- i - start + 1
    div_b_old <- div_b - 1

    if (div_b <= 1) {
      div_b <- 1
      div_b_old <- 1
    }

    undo <- max_ending_here * sqrt(div_b_old)
    max_ending_here <- max(current, (undo + current) / sqrt(div_b))

    if (max_ending_here == current) {
      start <- i
    }

    max_so_far <- max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)

    if (max_ending_here < 0) {
      start <- i + 1
    } else if (max_ending_here == max_so_far) {
      start_old <- start
      end <- i
    }
  }

  start <- start_old + 1
  new_max <- max_so_far
  div_b_old <- end - start_old + 1
  div_b <- div_b_old - 1

  while (start < end) {
    new_max <- (new_max * sqrt(div_b_old) - arr[start - 1]) / sqrt(div_b)

    if (new_max > max_so_far) {
      max_so_far <- new_max
      start_old <- start
    }

    start <- start + 1
    div_b <- div_b - 1
    div_b_old <- div_b_old - 1

    if (div_b < 1) {
      break
    }
  }

  return (list(max_so_far, start_old, end))
}

arr <- c(1, -3, -4, 2, 6, 8, -4, -3, -5, 1, 7, -9, 3, 2)

cat("Input array: ", paste(arr, collapse = " "), "\n")

result <- calculate_max_normalized_mean_subarray(arr)

cat("Max normalized mean: ", result[[1]], "\n")
cat("starting index: ", result[[2]], "\n")
cat("ending index: ", result[[3]], "\n")
```

C++ program [**Playground Link**](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/online-cpp14-compiler/2e4799e3-412f-4c1a-8921-3cbddb11fd9d)

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Tuple = {Max normalized mean, starting index, ending index}
tuple<double, int, int> calculate_max_normalized_mean_subarray(const vector<int>& arr) {
    double max_so_far = arr[0], max_ending_here = arr[0];
    int start_old = 0, start = 0, end = 0, div_b = 1, div_b_old = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        int current = arr[i];
        div_b = i - start + 1;
        div_b_old = div_b - 1;

        if (div_b <= 1) {
            div_b = 1;
            div_b_old = 1;
        }

        double undo = max_ending_here * sqrt(div_b_old);
        max_ending_here = max(static_cast<double>(current), (undo + current) / sqrt(div_b));

        if (max_ending_here == current)
            start = i;

        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);

        if (max_ending_here < 0) {
            start = i + 1;
        } else if (max_ending_here == max_so_far) {
            start_old = start;
            end = i;
        }
    }

    start = start_old + 1;
    double new_max = max_so_far;
    div_b_old = end - start_old + 1;
    div_b = div_b_old - 1;

    while (start < end) {
        new_max = (new_max * sqrt(div_b_old) - arr[start - 1]) / sqrt(div_b);

        if (new_max > max_so_far) {
            max_so_far = new_max;
            start_old = start;
        }

        start++;
        div_b--;
        div_b_old--;

        if (div_b < 1)
            break;
    }

    return make_tuple(max_so_far, start_old, end);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> arr = {1, -3, -4, 2, 6, 8, -4, -3, -5, 1, 7, -9, 3, 2};

    cout << "Input array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    auto result = calculate_max_normalized_mean_subarray(arr);
    cout << "Max normalized mean: " << get<0>(result) << endl;
    cout << "starting index: " << get<1>(result) << endl;
    cout << "ending index: " << get<2>(result) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relative to the problem that Kadane's algorithm solves, you've lost optimal substructure, so this algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't think so. Can you provide an example for your argument, or why did you think it has lost the optimal substructure? Here, the maximum normalized mean subarray is calculated using the maximum normalized mean of the subarray ending at each index.

Comment: Well, the burden of proof that you have a correct algorithm is on you, but it gives the wrong answer on 100 50 0 151 100.

Comment: This is very close! Better than my O(n) version in terms of accuracy. However if you ```set.seed(10)```, you'll find the max_so_far is smaller than the true max, which is 4.433735. same for ```seed(17)```. But again, mine algorithm had 4 errors where yours only had 2.